# Implementing range slider in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, uislider

I am currently trying to use a range slider to manipulate the bars on my Chart.js graph. However, even though I have the code written, which I used from a previous project, it still won't work. I have attached the code below, and if someone can tell me why clicking sliding the range slider won't change the bar graph.

I have two main pieces of code:

```
<input type="range" class="slider" value="5" min="30" max="50" id="points" onchange="function()">

var heating [] =  parseInt(document.querySelector('#points').value);
```

Essentially, the heating variable is assigned to this, and then by `onchange` the function is run. Now, I'm not sure why it's not happening as of now. If someone can check, that would be great. I am attaching all the code below.

***INDEX.HTML FILE***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Montserrat|Tangerine">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container">
    <canvas id="chart" style="font-family: 'Tangerine', serif; font-size: 1.9em;"></canvas>
    <form action="test.php" method="get">
      <label>BlockGroup<input  class="flex-wrapper"  type="text" name="BlockGroup"  placeholder="60014431031" ><br><br>    
        <label>Zip Code: <input style=" display:inline;" class="flex-wrapper"   type="text" name="ZipCode"  placeholder="94538"><br><br>    
        <label>City: <input style=" display:inline;" class="flex-wrapper"   type="text" name="City"  placeholder="Fremont"><br><br>    
        <label>State: <input style=" display:inline;" class="flex-wrapper" type="text" name="State"  placeholder="California"><br><br>    
        <!-- <label>County: <input style=" display:inline;" class="flex-wrapper"  id="myInput" type="text" name="County"  placeholder="Alameda" value='<?php echo $firstname; ?>' ><br><br> -->    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
    </form>    
  </div>    
  <button id="shuffle">Sort Data</button>    
  <br>
  <p> <b> Heating Electrification <b> <p>
    <input type="range" class="slider" value="5" min="30" max="50"  id="points" onchange="function()">    
  <!-- javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

***APP.JS***

```
const CHART = document.getElementById("chart");
var barChart = [];

Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 3000;
Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeUpdate: function(chart) {
    if (chart.options.sort) {
      // Get the data from each datasets.
      var dataArray = [];
      $.each(chart.data.datasets, function() {
        dataArray.push(this.data);
      });
      // Get the index after sorted.
      let dataIndexes = dataArray.map((d, i) => i);
      dataIndexes.sort((a, b) => {
        return dataArray[a] - dataArray[b];
      });
      // create after sorted datasets.
      var tempDatasets = [];
      $.each(dataIndexes, function() {
        tempDatasets.push(chart.data.datasets[this]);
      });
      // apply it
      chart.data.datasets = tempDatasets;
      return tempDatasets;
    }
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8888/test.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var sample = [];
      var electric = [];
      var mpg = [];
      var urban = [];
      var vmt = [];
      var airtravel = [];
      var renewable = [];
      var conservation = [];
      var heating = [];
      var water = [];
      var cefficiency = [];
      var shiftc = [];
      var healthyd = [];
      var heating[] = parseInt(document.querySelector('#points').value);

      for (var i in data) {
        sample.push(data[i].sample);
        electric.push(parseInt(data[i].electric));
        mpg.push(parseInt(data[i].mpg));
        urban.push(parseInt(data[i].urban));
        vmt.push(parseInt(data[i].vmt));
        airtravel.push(parseInt(data[i].airtravel));
        renewable.push(parseInt(data[i].renewable));
        conservation.push(parseInt(data[i].conservation));
        heating.push(parseInt(data[i].heating));
        water.push(parseInt(data[i].water));
        cefficiency.push(parseInt(data[i].cefficiency));
        shiftc.push(parseInt(data[i].shiftc));
        healthyd.push(parseInt(data[i].healthyd));
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: sample,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Electric Vehicles",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,235,243,0.8)",
            data: electric,
            stack: 1
          },
          {
            label: "50+ MPG Vehicles",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(120,255,0,0.8)",
            data: mpg,
            stack: 2
          },
          {
            label: "Urban Infill",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,235,243,0.8)",
            data: urban,
            stack: 3
          },
          {
            label: "VMT Reduction",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(120,255,0,0.8)",
            data: vmt,
            stack: 4
          },
          {
            label: "Air Travel Reduction",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,235,243,0.8)",
            data: airtravel,
            stack: 5
          },
          {
            label: "Renewable Electricity",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(120,255,0,0.8)",
            data: renewable,
            stack: 6
          },
          {
            label: "Energy Eficiency and Conservation",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,235,243,0.8)",
            data: conservation,
            stack: 7
          },
          {
            label: "Heating Electrification",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(120,255,0,0.8)",
            data: heating,
            stack: 8
          },
          {
            label: "Water & Waste",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,235,243,0.8)",
            data: water,
            stack: 9
          },
          {
            label: "Commercial Efficiency",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,235,243,0.8)",
            data: cefficiency,
            stack: 10
          },

          {
            label: "Shift Consumption",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,235,243,0.8)",
            data: shiftc,
            stack: 11
          },
          {
            label: "Healthy Diets",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(120,255,0,0.8)",
            data: healthyd,
            stack: 12
          },
        ]
      };

      barChart = new Chart(CHART, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: chartdata,
      });

    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

document.getElementById('shuffle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  barChart.options.sort = true;
  barChart.update();
  barChart.options.sort = true;
});
```

Also, here is a picture of the above situation. When sliding my range slider nothing happens, so I am sort of concerned:

[image: HTML File on Web Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you still get motivated to solve this problem?
It's an easy thing, really. However, you need to understand a little bit more how it works.

First of all, you wrote this code on the $(document).ready, that means this code is only ran after page ready.(once)
There's no way that the chart is updated.

```
var heating[] = parseInt(document.querySelector('#points').value);
```

Also, you added event.

```
<input type="range" class="slider" value="5" min="30" max="50" id="points" onchange="function()">
```

This fact shows me you really don't understand things.
Usually, you need to call a function, like this.

```
<input type="range" class="slider" value="5" min="30" max="50" id="points" onchange="testFunction()">

function testFunction() {
    // update chart...
}
```

Or add event (this time I use jQuery)

```
<input type="range" class="slider" value="5" min="30" max="50" id="points">

$("#points").on("change", function() {
    // update chart...
});
```

Lastly, to update Chart.js, you need to update the value in the datasets, and call its update method. You can updated a just one datasets.

```
// Get heating datasets. (Yes, you can write 'barGraph.data.datasets[7].data = xxx')
var heatDatasts = barGraph.data.datasets[7];
// Update value
heatDatasts.data = [$(this).val()];
// Apply it to the view.
barGraph.update();
```

If you can't use a debug tool, I recommend at least use an alert.
(I used in the jsfiddle)
That way you can tell either the code is run or not.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sy61tkwn/)

***UPDATED1***
For first question.
I updated the image, and I hope you understand.
There are various way, but I pick up the two.
[image: Explain]

```
/*************** Pattern1 (Simply, using jQuery each) ***************/
// Loop
$.each(barGraph.data.datasets, function() {
    // Check the label or stack, in this case.
    if (this.label === "Heating Electrification") {
        // It's okay
        // heatDatasets = this;
        // Set value is also okay.
        this.data = [sliderValue];
        return false;
    }
});
 /*************** Pattern2 (using jQuery grep or filter)***************/
 var heatDatasets = $.grep(barGraph.data.datasets, function(datasets) {
     return (datasets.label === "Heating Electrification");
 })[0];
 heatDatasets.data = [sliderValue];
```

The second question.
Basically, we don't use JavaScript variable on HTML.
Some framework or library can looks like it can be possible, though.

```
// Set value, min and max.
// We can't use JavaScript variable on HTML, usually.
var slider = $("#points");
slider.prop("min", 0);
slider.prop("max", 1000);
slider.val(1000);
```

[For example](https://jsfiddle.net/hxr62c9p/)

***UPDATED2***
I found that datasets can have any parameters, so you can add parameters anything.
For example, I added 'barId' and modified the sliders(add id, which is the same as 'barId'.)
[For example](https://jsfiddle.net/9r4bungf/)

Comment: hi , thanks so much for your response. It worked, and I really appreciate all the help you have given me. Quick question, however, is it not possible to assign the input ranges to specific variables. Instead of eah dataset, because when sorting the data after I toggle the input ranges, it doesnt correspond to the same variable. I tried something like this:

Comment: var heatDatasts = barGraph.data.datasets[mpg]; but it didnt work

Comment: Also, is it possible to have custom min and max ranges, which would make it a lot easier. Because when I get data from each location, I dont want to have preset data ranges, but instead more flexiibility. For example, <input type="range" class="slider" value="5" min="30" max="50" id="points">, in this the min="0 and max ="this.currentvalue(mpg) or any specific variable. Harcording the min and max as you may be aware is not that efficiency

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you meant by what other parameter. Would it not just be var heatDatasts = barGraph.data.datasets[mpg];

Comment: I mean the columns that I update the image, label, backgroundColor, and so on. I’ll show you later, including the second question.

Comment: Cool thanks so much, please tell me as soon as possible if you can. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, have a look.

Comment: hey man, i really appeciate you. Like for real, its amazing how helpful you are.

Comment: and for my second question, thats not exactly what  i meant. I was meaning something like so when I initially get my data from my database, say its 90,000. How can I specify the max value in the input range to be 90,000 without having to hardcode 90,000 in the slider.prop box. I was thinking something like slider.prop("max", barCharts.data.datasets.label =="Heating Electrification");

Comment: Would that be correct, Im not sure if you think thats right

Comment: Of course, you can change that part using variable. I've some tested now, and found Chart.js is more flexiable than I thought. wait a minute.

Comment: I do have a quick question however, when .I try to run the code you provided for my case, it doesnt work for some reason. The console is not showing any error either. Any thoughts or suggestions that you might have. I updated the app.js code if you could take a look.

Comment: oh sorry, it was on my end! No Worries, all good over here, thanks for all your help buddy!!!! If you need any assitance in the future, please feel free to contact me

Comment: No Problem, Im sorry to bother you like this, but Im so new to coding that having someone like you to help me is one of the best things, especially to learn from an experienced developer. I only have one final inquiry which I could not get answered. If you have any input on this, please feel free to comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487777/updating-html-graph-with-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment89945003_51487777     Thats the link, but i couldnt find the help i needed.

Comment: Yeah, when it comes to the web, especially just like you are doing now, we just need knowledge. We don't need to be smart, I think. Take it easy. I'll explain to you until the end of tomorrow.